# Fetching tweets with hashtag from Twitter using Python

Tags: python, twitter, twython

How do we find or fetch tweets on the basis of hash tag. i.e. I want to find tweets regarding on a certain subject? Is it possible in Python using Twython?

Thanks

Comment: check out the following link. I've worked on it a bit. It might be helpful. https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/112388584507961481820/112388584507961481820/posts

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT**
My original solution using Twython's hooks for the Search API appears to be no longer valid because Twitter now wants users authenticated for using Search. To do an authenticated search via Twython, just supply your Twitter authentication credentials when you initialize the Twython object.   Below, I'm pasting an example of how you can do this, but you'll want to consult the Twitter API documentation for [GET/search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) to understand the different optional parameters you can assign in your searches (for instance, to page through results, set a date range, etc.)

```
from twython import Twython

TWITTER_APP_KEY = 'xxxxxx'  #supply the appropriate value
TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET = 'xxxxxx' 
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxx'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxx'

t = Twython(app_key=TWITTER_APP_KEY, 
            app_secret=TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET, 
            oauth_token=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
            oauth_token_secret=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

search = t.search(q='#omg',   #**supply whatever query you want here**
                  count=100)

tweets = search['statuses']

for tweet in tweets:
  print tweet['id_str'], '\n', tweet['text'], '\n\n\n'
```

---

**Original Answer**

As indicated [here in the Twython documentation](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/core_examples/search_results.py), you can use Twython to access the Twitter Search API:

```
from twython import Twython
twitter = Twython()
search_results = twitter.search(q="#somehashtag", rpp="50")

for tweet in search_results["results"]:
    print "Tweet from @%s Date: %s" % (tweet['from_user'].encode('utf-8'),tweet['created_at'])
    print tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'),"\n"
```

etc...   Note that for any given search, you're probably going to max out at around 2000 tweets at most, going back up to around a week or two. You can read more about the Twitter Search API [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets).

Comment: hey Thanks again ,but i am getting an error while i do this The following is an error which i am getting.                       Is it that it requires authentication

Comment: TwythonError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/vishal/<ipython-input-3-241f789b11cc> in <module>()
----> 1 search_results = twitter.search(q="#india", rpp="50")

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.5-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.pyc in search(self, **kwargs)
    365         """
    366 
--> 367         return self.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json', params=kwargs)
    368 
    369     def searchGen(self, search_query, **kwargs):

Comment: usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.5-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.pyc in get(self, endpoint, params, version)
     236 
    237     def get(self, endpoint, params=None, version='1.1'):
--> 238         return self.request(endpoint, params=params, version=version)
    239 
    240     def post(self, endpoint, params=None, files=None, version='1.1'):

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.5-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.pyc in request(self, endpoint, method, params, files, version)
           231             url = '%s/%s.json' % (self.api_url % version, endpoint)
    232 
--> 233         content = self._request(url, method=method, params=params, files=files, api_call=url)
    234 
    235         return content

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.5-py2.7.egg <br)/twython/twython.pyc in _request(self, url, method, params, files, api_call)<br>
    208             raise exceptionType(error_msg,
    209                                 error_code=response.status_code,
--> 210                                 retry_after=response.headers.get('retry-after'))
    211 
    212         # if we have a json error here, then it's not an official TwitterAPI error

Comment: Hey Thanks Benjamin..................Cheers.I owe you beer for this buddy

Comment: The link to the docs in the second part is broken, please update the answer soon

Comment: A currently working docs link which seems to have some of the same info is https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/docs/usage/basic_usage.rst